# composite_primary_keys - How to pass both from view to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed composite_primary_keys, and set my two primary keys.  My delete method works, as it doesn't need to pass any id's.  However I am unsure how to get my edit path to function.

If I leave it including only the default :id, I get this message (as expected)

```
Incorrect number of primary keys for Deal: ["id", "merchant_id"]
```

I have found that for the edit form to render, I effectively have to make the URL look this this

```
http://localhost:3000/deals/2,1/edit
```

My attempts to get both values into the edit_deals_path() have not worked.

Is there a tutorial somewhere on how to use composite_primary_keys gem?  The author's website doesn't include this issue.